# Make color legend float right in same line as other div

Tags: html, css, button, user-interface, label

I need to make a color legend be on the right side of the window in the same line as a title+button. Right now it looks like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/MTB2q/80/

```
<ul class="legend">
    <li><span class="superawesome"></span> Super Awesome</li>
    <li><span class="awesome"></span> Awesome</li>
    <li><span class="kindaawesome"></span> Kinda Awesome</li>
<li><span class="notawesome"></span> Not Awesome</li>
</ul>

<div style="text-align: center">
 <label ID="contentTitle">TITLE</label>
</div>

<div style="text-align: center">
 <button ID="contentButton">button</button>
</div>

.legend { list-style: none; }
.legend span { border: 1px solid #ccc; float: left; width: 12px; height: 12px; margin: 2px; }

.legend .superawesome { background-color: #ff00ff; }
.legend .awesome { background-color: #00ffff; }
.legend .kindaawesome { background-color: #0000ff; }
.legend .notawesome { background-color: #000000; }
```

As you can see, the colors are on the right side of the words, I need them to be on the left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the float of the span to left and the float of the legend to right fixed the issue.

Comment: It doesn't fit the screen and also the colors are on the right side of the words now, I need them to be on the left side of the words.

Comment: @SKLAK, The colors are still in their original position on my browser, which is the left side.

Comment: Ok, this fits the screen: http://jsfiddle.net/MTB2q/80/ but the colors are still on the right side of the words for me hmm.. must be browser dependent.

Comment: @SKLAK, K, I see now that all you were trying to do was float the ul to the right.

Comment: so you still see the colors on the left of the labels in your browser with the new jsfiddle?

Comment: @SKLAK, nope! The colors are now on the right of the labels, and the whole <ul> is floated right. You asked and answered your question buddy, lol.

Comment: Haha I guess I did. I didn't include the fact that I need the colors on the left side of the labels. I've updated the question. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55401/discussion-between-charles-and-sklak).

Answer (score 0):

Gave this a quick test in IE 11 and Chrome:

```
<ul id="legend">
    <li class="superawesome"><div>Super Awesome</div></li>
    <li class="awesome"><div>Awesome</div></li>
    <li class="kindaawesome"><div>Kinda Awesome</div></li>
    <li class="notawesome"><div>Not Awesome</div></li>
</ul>

<div style="text-align: center">
   <label ID="contentTitle">TITLE</label>
</div>

<div style="text-align: center">
   <button ID="contentButton">button</button>
</div>
```

CSS tweaked as follows:

```
#legend { list-style: none; float: right; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#legend li { margin: 0 0 2px 0; padding: 0 0 0 12px; }
#legend div { width: 100%; background-color: white; padding-left: 2px; }
/* your colors */
#legend .superawesome { background-color: #ff00ff; }
#legend .awesome { background-color: #00ffff; }
#legend .kindaawesome { background-color: #0000ff; }
#legend .notawesome { background-color: #000000; }
```